# Unable to record Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to JMeter and trying to record a JMeter script on firefox but getting an error message

Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.Try to add the link to trusted sites.

-In Firefox go to the Open Menu (Upper right 3 lines)

-Locate and select the “Security” tab.

-Click on the “Exceptions…” button.

- Next type in the internet address you would like to remain trusted EX: 
  *.test.com

-Click “Close” then “OK” to complete this action.

2. Try recording with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have followed all the steps below and especially the browser side configuration:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

If your site is HTTPS, I would suggest you to use Blazemeter Plugin for Chrome to record your tests without much hassles and then export it later into Jmeter.